# Custom start index in Julia array?

Tags: arrays, julia

How do you declare an array with a **custom start index** in Julia?

In other words, when I declare an array under special circumstances, how can I make the first element's index *0* or *2* instead of *1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: there is no built-in way to do this in Julia.

Long answer: you can make a custom array type that would support this fairly easily, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428078/fortran-like-arrays-such-as-farrayfloat64-11-77-128512-in-julia) has good solutions for this problem.